# why the same color looks different on different android devices

Tags: android, colors, rgb

I find lots of colors look different on different android devices. For example, if I set #fff8f5ea as the background color of a View and run the app on different devices, I can easily tell the difference between them.
Any body have the same problem? Does anyone know why?

Comment: It is related to hardware, just have a look at this http://www.androidpit.com/super-amoled-vs-retina-display

Comment: Depends on the screen..(Hardware)

Comment: you can add a image as background if u wanna it appear the same :)

Comment: interesting topic, can someone suggest most neutral colors that would look unchanged on diffrent devices?

Answer (score 9):

Every piece of hardware will render the primary colours used in the individual pixels at different intensities.

The display driver also implements colour profiles, sometimes user definable, which alter those intensities.

I can load an image on my Galaxy S3 and chose a different profile under Settings->Display->Screen mode to render the image in different colour spaces.

Comment: I find something more interesting. If I create a web page and set some element's color to for example #fff8f5ea, and then use a web browser to show the web page, the color looks exactly the same on different devices. My God! What Happened???

Comment: That part helped a lot: "Galaxy S3 and chose a different profile under Settings -> Display -> Screen mode". Turned into mode natural / movie to get a red that was closer to the red I had on my screen. But still frustrating to know that it can make a big difference.

Comment: Does the emulator has its own display driver? I compare the app in emulator with webpage in the pc browser, and found the same color has huge difference on the same monitor.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, the devices use a different screen type.

Colors vary between LCDs, LEDs and other screen types because of the way the screen is built.

For example, some screens will turn pixels of completely to display black, while some will show a shade of grey.

Comment: @I-droid Even with images, colors will differ

Comment: what can we do to have consistence view of app on various devices ?

Comment: @I-droid You can't. Its a hardware/ROM setting.