# Issues with background colour rendering

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

The background colour that I am using for my splash screen is rendering very differently on samsung duos(GT-I8232).By different i mean its contrast,brightness and sharpness is completely changed resulting in a very different colour than the one i originally composed in an image editor(Chasys IE artist) and then used in Eclipse.

Also the background does not have any problem rendering on other devices and Android virtual device.

The other apps(available on playstore) that use this colour seems to be rendering it properly on samsung duos.

Also this problems only seems to be in the shades of green colour.Please suggest a solution.Appreciate your help in Advance!

Solution I have tried:
1)I have tried using different image formats like png,jpeg etc. but with no results

Comment: Take a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540361/why-the-same-color-looks-different-on-different-android-devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540361/why-the-same-color-looks-different-on-different-android-devices)

Comment: @Nizam: Thank you for your reply, but it doesnt solve my problem only recognizes it.The thing is utorrent app uses almost the same colour.So if they are able to render it properly on my device then i want to know the solution because there is a way atleast in this case.Anyways appreciate your help! ;)