# The color is shown differently on some devices

Tags: android

I have a strange problem. On my app, I have Resources set into a gray scale:

```
<color name="gray_light">#eeeeee</color>
<color name="gray">#ddddde</color>
```

The problem is that in some devices (example Samsung Galaxy) the color is shown correctly, but on others (like Motorola Razr) it's shown green.

The color is applied on a background (Relativelayout / background) and as a divider list.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvFilters"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/gray"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
</ListView>
```

Do you know what is happening?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post some screenshots, plus the actual `<color>` definition?

Comment: Sorry, I can't show you the app :S

Comment: Try `#ffeeeeee` and `#ffddddde` and see if that changes the behavior. Also, try increasing the divider height and see if that changes anything. Also also, note that your `ListView` is not using either of the resources that you have added to your question.

Comment: @sany How do you expect us to help you with color-related issues if we can't see the color issues? My guess the screens are calibrated differently, but there is no way for me to know without seeing.

Comment: may be this is the reason http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540361/why-the-same-color-looks-different-on-different-android-devices

Comment: Your ListView uses `@color/gray_wtf` but that's not in your `<color>` definition.  Besides that, without actual screenshots, there's nothing we can help you with.