# Android images color variety in different phones

Tags: android, android-image, android-glide, android-color

In my app images color varies in different phones.

All  images have 1920 x 1080 resolution.

I am just showing them in a listview and using Glide to display images.

You can see the attachment, I don't know what is reason of it can anyone tell me.

[image]

Comment: May i know where you put this image(folder like drawable-xhdpi) ??

Comment: Feeling sad for your sony device. ;-)

Comment: As my images are very large in size so put them in drawable-nodpi.

Answer (score 4):

All devices pick colors at different intensities. You cannot do much about it. Its hardware that renders the images and colors in it. If you want consistency among all devices you have to calibrate your monitor.  [This](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/monitor-calibration.htm) link might be useful

Comment: To be more specific, color calibration is a problem common to every display, from smartphone panels to TVs to projecors. Most of the time people just ignore the problem, since the human visual system compensates for the differences. It's only when you put different panels side by side that the differences are obvious.

Comment: Thanks Hammad, yes i can understand about hardware limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Basically that is not the issue from developer sides. One thing you should remember that the different colors look different in different devices because of their display settings and their display screens and manufacturer of the device display.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Type of Display It will Appear different shades..

Mostly we have LED,and LCD.. screens.. In LED If we Take Super Amoled It will show  very fine and HD color full images... also Based on Pixel We will see HD images... But diff shades means its depend on Display type...

For IPS some less clarity ... like that check [this](http://www.in.techradar.com/news/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/Best-phone-screen-display-tech-explained/articleshow/38997644.cms) and [this](https://www.androidpit.com/smartphone-displays-explained) for more displays types  android

Answer (score 0):

I also had some of devices and I noticed that same Image will be looking different in color in all device.

This will happen because of density ration of Display and quality of display.

Same question you can see from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540361/why-the-same-color-looks-different-on-different-android-devices)