# Certain physical device shows different background color than selected and showed by other devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I was testing my app in different devices and I have a problem in one of them where the background color of my app is totally different than the one I want to see.

My xml and other devices show the color correctly, but on this phone (photo below) the color is different.

[image: My physical device background]

[image: My emulated device and xml in android studio background color]

I have to add that this is not the only physical device that I've tested with, the others devices work correctly adding the background color that I want.

This is the color that I have in my values/colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="background">#25D366</color>
</resources>
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: can you post this device model?

Comment: here is a similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540361/why-the-same-color-looks-different-on-different-android-devices

Comment: Xiaomi Mi 9 Lite

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the material design you can suppress this by:

```
backgroundTint="@null"
```

Answer (score 0):

according to posted device: `Xiaomi Mi 9 Lite` - Xiaomi have some auto-dark-mode feature in theirs awesome MIUI, which oftenly breaks app styles. I've seen layout which was "light" and this mode set black background and white text for whole app. but some of `TextView`s had some additional own background set to white color, so text was invisible... imho worth check